# Junior Mobile FW - loading views from html

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, mobile, backbone.js

I just started a new project with [Junior](http://justspamjustin.github.com/junior/#home).

I think it's all pretty straight forward but what really bothers me is that the views (meaning the content of the pages) is currently just a long JS string, which is horrible.

I can't build my mobile app like that because I need a single html file for every page with its own JS scripts and stuff.

I used jQuery Mobile before but I HATE designing a JQ Mobile App because I have to overwrite pretty much anyhting to start from scratch which is of course not an elegant solution.

So my question is:

Do you know of any nice way to load the content of each page within my mobile app?!
Ajax doesnt work (not even in async: false mode) it just always gives me undefined.

Here is the script junior uses to load the views: [JS](http://justspamjustin.github.com/junior/docs/example.html)

Hope someone can help! :-)

btw: jQuery Mobile does just what I want (it loads the other views via ajax into a div and when it's ready it does the transition.) But again: I don't want to use jQMob because of this horrible CSS problem.

best regards
Patrick

Comment: Why don't use some templating solution such as underscore's microtemplating, jquery templates, handlebars or something? You could also lazy load them with RequireJS + text plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [underscore's microtemplating solution](http://underscorejs.org/#template) to load the templates from the dom:

```
// In your HTML:
<script type="text/template" id="myPageTemplate">
  <div id="myPage">
    <p>Hello!</p>
  </div>
</script>
```

Then you can load them in `javascript` like this and get the same result, yet keeping the markup in the html:

```
var template = _.template( $('#myPageTemplate').html() , {});
```

There are lots of similar templating solutions but the process to load them and compile them tends to be very similar. Other solutions you may ike to take a look at:

- [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)
- [Moustache](http://mustache.github.com)